# Applications using JRE and graphics crashing

Tags: fedora, java, gtk, jdk

We recently updated our computers to Fedora 27 and one of our applications (COMSOL) has stopped working. When I attempt to run COMSOL, I get the following error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000000070f0, pid=7235, tid=140187788225408
 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_75-b13) (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.75-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  0x00000000000070f0
 Core dump written. Default location: /home/pjahelka/core or core.7235
 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /home/pjahelka/hs_err_pid7235.log
 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

/usr/local/comsol52/multiphysics_copy1/bin/comsol: line 1614:  7235 Aborted                 (core dumped) ${MPICMD} ${FLROOT}/bin/${ARCH}/comsollauncher --launcher.ini ${LAUNCHERINIFILE} ${LAUNCHERARGS} ${MPILAUNCHERARGS}
```

Here is the error log: http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1517875372163.txt

In addition, I can't run the installer for COMSOL either. Attempting to do so causes terminal to output the following:

```
(Setuplauncher:8865): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(Setuplauncher:8865): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_font_description: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_base_dir: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_language: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_new: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_text: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_attributes: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_alignment: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_ellipsize: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_single_paragraph_mode: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_width: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_extents: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_size_lookup_for_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-WARNING **: Invalid icon size 6


(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_load_icon: assertion 'GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'dialog-error' for stock: 

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_size_lookup_for_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-WARNING **: gtkstyle.c:2358: invalid icon size '6'

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_style_render_icon: assertion 'pixbuf != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_font_description: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_base_dir: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_language: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_new: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_text: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_alignment: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_ellipsize: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_single_paragraph_mode: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_wrap: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_width: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_extents: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_font_description: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_base_dir: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_language: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_new: assertion 'context != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_text: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_extents: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_width: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_extents: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(Setuplauncher:8865): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_line_count: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGFPE (0x8) at pc=0x00007f31aad167c7, pid=8865, tid=0x00007f31f3a3b740

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_112-b15) (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x1397c7]

 Core dump written. Default location: /home/pjahelka/Downloads/COMSOL53a_lnx/core or core.8865

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /home/pjahelka/Downloads/COMSOL53a_lnx/hs_err_pid8865.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Aborted (core dumped)
Removing temporary COMSOL installer components...
```

The corresponding log file is here: http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1517875632800.txt

I apologize if this is the wrong forum for these errors, but I'm not even sure where to start so any pointers would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken this to COMSOL support?

Comment: Yes. I'm working with them in parallel on this issue. I'm really hoping for a more sophisticated solution than reinstalling the OS.

Comment: Try if deleting/renaming your local configuration directory `~/.comsol` fixes the problem.